# Date formatting in terminal

Tags: terminal

I am trying to format the date function in terminal. So I get the format:
`2021-08-31 12:02:54`
I have been playing around but can't seem to get the `-` in the format.
Any ideas?

```
date '+%y%-m%-d %X'
```

This just makes one long number with no lines in between.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out: `date '+%Y-%m-%d %X'`